# What are the differences between the difficulties in Affordable Space Adventures?

Tags: affordable-space-adventures

Affordable Space Adventures starts off with 3 difficulty levels - Technical, Tourist, and a third mode that is (clearly, due to labeling) the hard mode.

What are the differences among these, especially between Technical and Tourist?

Comment: I know nothing about the game, but "tourist" suggests a "casual" difficulty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm one of the developers of this game, and I can answer this for you :)

- Technical is "Normal".
- Tourist is "Easy", where some of the puzzles
  have been made easier.
- Origin Story is a completely separate set of
  levels that were released as free DLC. These levels contains the
  puzzles that were deemed "too hard" for the original story, plus some new ones.

Hope you enjoy the game!

Comment: Really cool to see a developer on here! Just to let you know, my pals and I really enjoy ASA.

Comment: Excellent, a definitive answer, thanks! And yes my daughter and I have been having a lot of fun with it.